# Changing Values on the Same Column for Different DataFrames (in R)

Tags: r, variables, for-loop

I have the following situation:

I have 17 different DataFrames, all of them have the same column (**COD_MOEDA**)
I have a Vector (**NAME_DATAFRAME**) that contains the 17 variable names of the DataFrames

I am trying to loop in all Dataframes in order to apply the condition : for all values == 0 on column COD_MOEDA on all DATAFRAMES, change it to “BRL”

I tried concatenating the condition on a variable (**ConditionString**), but i am not able to apply the rule using ConditionString <- "BRL":

```
for (i in 1:17)
{

ConditionString <-paste(NAME_DATAFRAME[i],"&COD_MOEDA[",NAME_DATAFRAME[i],"&COD_MOEDA==0”],sep=””)

(??)

}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: It sounds like your data is not arranged in a way that makes it easy for you to access. I would suggest storing all of the data frames in a list and then performing operations on that list; in general this is a lot easier than looking up variables by name.

Comment: If you want to keep your frames the way they are, get() might be of help. In your loop you add df=get(NAME_DATAFRAME[i]), and then you just work with df. In the end you can use assign() to put the new data.frame under the old name. Thought josliber's idea would be far more efficient..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situations like this where you are trying to manipulate objects by name (as a character string), the `get` and `assign` functions are your friend. Here is a solution that loops through each data.frame by name.

```
for (df in NAME_DATAFRAME) {

    # Get the current dataframe by name
    y <- get(df, pos = globalenv())

    # Do stuff
    y$COD_MOEDA[y$COD_MOEDA == 0] <- 'BRL'

    # Assign the new dataframe back to its name
    assign(df, y, pos = globalenv())

    # Tidy up
    rm(y)
}
rm(df)
```

However, this is not a very "R-like" solution because R is not particularly efficient at loops. As @josliber points out, you'll have better performance (and readability) if you store your dataframes in a list and use `apply` functions to operate on each in sequence.

You may be able to get your dataframes into a list by altering your upstream code, but here's an easy way to get there from your current state:

```
list_of_dataframes <- sapply(
    NAME_DATAFRAME,
    get,
    pos = globalenv(),
    simplify = FALSE
)
```

From here, you can use the `lapply` function to manipulate each dataframe.

```
list_of_modified_dataframes <- lapply(
    list_of_dataframes,
    function(x) {
        # Inside this function, `x` represents a single dataframe

        # Do stuff
        x$COD_MOEDA[x$COD_MOEDA == 0] <- 'BRL'

        # And return the modified dataframe
        return(x)
    }
)
```

I'm not sure what your ultimate goal is, but be aware that assigning the character string 'BRL' implicitly converts your column from numeric to character. This means that subsequent numeric conditional statements (e.g. COD_MOEDA > 42) will not work.

Comment: Thanks @FascinatingFingers , the use of list with dataframes works even when the mentioned DF doesnt have the same number of columns and doesnt have the same information ?

Comment: @RiskTech, yes. Simply putting objects into a list does not require any assumptions about class/structure. You can have a list of unrelated dataframes, or even a mix of dataframes, scalars, nested lists, anything. Note that in this example, the "Do stuff" section of the function does assume that each dataframe at least has a "COD_MOEDA" column.

Comment: Amazing, i was able to change the code to work with lists. Thanks a lot !