# Working with Columns in a List of DataFrames in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes called **Lista_DF**, some DF on this list have a column called **COD_MOEDA**.

I am trying to substitute all 0 values for "BRL" on the DF's that have a column named **COD_MOEDA**, and iam using :

```
Lista_DF <- lapply(Lista_DF,function(x) 
{
   x$COD_MOEDA[x$COD_MOEDA == 0] <- 'BRL'
})
```

But i am getting this error :

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "COD_MOEDA", value = character(0)) : 
replacement has 0 rows, data has 3094
```

I believe it is due to the DF that don't have the column named **COD_MOEDA**

Any suggestions ?

This is a continuation of [Changing Values on the Same Column for Different DataFrames (in R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484936/changing-values-on-the-same-column-for-different-dataframes-in-r)

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you forgot the return statement which produce the error you get

```
replacement has 0 rows, data has 3094
```

Regarding to dealing with data.frame with no `CODE_MOEDA` just need an condition statement:

```
if (!is.na(match("COD_MOEDA", names(x)))) {
    x$COD_MOEDA[x$COD_MOEDA == 0] <- 'BRL'
}

return(x)
```